# Long-term probability of a Markov Chain with Absorbing States

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

Transition Matrix for States:
G, 20, 19, 18, 17
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0.38 & 0.05 & 0 & 0.57 & 0 \\
    0.315 & 0 & 0.1 & 0 & 0.585 \\
    0.63 & 0 & 0 & 0.37 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Where in its standard form, state G and state 20 are absorbing states.
I need help finding the long-term probability of ending up in state G or state 20, but I'm having problems with getting a result that actually makes sense.

From what I understand, I have to find F = (I-Q)^-1,
where Q =
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0.57 & 0 \\
    0.1 & 0 & 0.585 \\
    0 & 0.37 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and then the answer would be F x R, where R =
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0.38 & 0.05\\
    0.315 & 0\\
    0.63 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, the answer I obtained had negative values, which does not make sense in view that it is a long-term probability of being in state G or state 20.

more info:
I used PatrickJMT's videos (on youtube) on markov chains as a guide to self-learn on this topic

Edit:
My workings for-

(I-Q) =
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -0.57 & 1 \\
    -0.1 & 1 & -0.585 \\
    1 & -0.37 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I manually calculated the inverse of (I-Q) using Matrix of Minors -> Matrix of Cofactors -> Adjugate and then multiplying with 1/determinant, and it tallies with an online 3x3 matrix inverse calculator to:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    8.077835 & 2.061856 & -6.87165 \\
    -5 & 0 & 5 \\
    -9.92784 & -2.06186 & 9.721649 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Please double-check your work. This is obviously a computational mistake. $(I-Q)^{-1}$ is entrywise nonnegative. So is $R$. It is not possible that $(I-Q)^{-1}R$ contains any negative values.

Comment: Two corners should contain zeros.

Comment: I added my workings for (I-Q) and the inverse of (I-Q)
@TaneliHuuskonen which corners?

Comment: Those of $I-Q$, lower left and upper right.

Comment: Thanks @TaneliHuuskonen
it ended up being a simple misunderstanding of an identity matrix!

I'll close the question once I'm able to get to the answer.